How common is “you lot” for a group of exactly two persons and under what circumstances can it be used as such if any?
Something about “you lot” tells me that it can't really be used with a group of two persons and requires a somewhat bigger group being addressed as a unit, to what extent is that correct and if not what are the catches to using it with a group of two persons? I'm aware the expression is not the friendliest one and often expresses a mild degree of rudeness.

I'd recommend not using it with a group of 2 people: most sources say it's used to address a group. But I think you already know that? So why do you want to use it with 2 people? In what context do you want to use it? It sounds like you want to ask something more specific but are being vague for some reason.

Why can't you say "you two"?

(Just a note in passing—the phrase you lot is used also in Australian English, if we can believe the episode of The Doctor Blake Mysteries that I watched last night.)

A comment could be applicable to you lot even if just two of them are present to hear it first hand. And it can make a derisive comment a little less personal.

@PhilSweet Right, it refers to the group you're talking about, not necessarily the group you're talking to, if some members are missing. But it's still expected that the group is more than 2 people.

The expression “you lot” is commonly used in British English to refer to a group of people informally. It’s similar to “you guys” or “you all” and can be used for groups of any size, including two persons. The tone can imply rudeness or familiarity, depending on the context and delivery.
Sign in to myPascoConnect
Best Regards.

So let's say one person says to two friends who are dating “Are you lot planning to get married?” does that feel like natural usage to you? There's something off about it to me at least but I can't quite explain what it is.
